# How to deploy Python as backend on a Windows server?

Tags: python

I just started to learn Python. I have some C# experience. I am wondering how the Python codes are deployed. I can do the coding task in Python now. And the codes can work when I click Debug button in developing tool (like VS Code). I only know that Python can be packed as a EXE file (using pyInstaller) and give it to users on Windows PC. Is there any other way to deploy Python codes to a Windows server to let it run automatically? For example:

1. Python file is xxx.py,
2. For some pandas or Numpy codes, Python code is saved as a xxx.ipynb file.
   How should we deploy them to a Windows server? Should I still pack them as EXE file and use Task Scheduler in Windows to run the EXE file? Is there any other way to deploy it?

Comment: Have a look at Papermill (https://pypi.org/project/papermill/) which is something you can use to run notebooks automatically. Since you're new here: Please note that this kind of question goes against Stackoverflow rules (as a rule of thumb your question should include code and a reproducable example.)

Comment: Although there are some tools to package python as an exe, usually it is not deployed that way. Rather one usually runs it from the source code. To make sure the right version of python is available to run it and with the right packages usually something called a python virtual environment is set up, which has a python exe that the python code is supposed to run with.